# Stock Android phone with IR and FM radio

Tags: android, smartphones

Important:

- 5" size (5.5" is problematic for pockets and hands).
- CAT 4 LTE or better with bands 3/7/20 (1800/2600/800MHz).
- Almost a given today, but 64bit CPU.
- 3+GB RAM.
- 16+GB flash ROM.
- SD card slot, accessible without removing back/battery.
- IR/remote capability.
- Stock or near-stock Android. I detest unnecessary software gimmicks.
- Unlocked.

Fairly important:

- 3000+mAh battery, preferably removable.
- FM radio (DAB would obviously also be OK).
- Ideally dual SIM (shared second SIM/SD card slot acceptable).
- Ideally big.LITTLE CPU design with the big/fast cores being out of order execution ARM v8.
- Good WiFi (dual band?) as it will work as home internet/router.

Unimportant:

- Cameras.
- High screen resolution - 720x1280 is fine.
- CPU clock frequencies.
- Thin/fancy/too light design. Solid is better.

Ulefone Power looks good (battery fixed, but large), if only it wasn't so big.

LG G5 also looks reasonable, except battery is a bit small, screen resolution is unnecessarily high and it is still rather big. Oh, and 4 times the price of the Ulefone(!).

Any better ideas?

Comment: I compromised on size and CPU with the good value Ulefone Power. It is perilous for the device for me to use it with one hand; I have to always check/adjust my pocket when bending/sitting down, but it isn't as bad as I thought. What else can I say if anybody is interested.. It isn't very loud. Fingerprint sensor works well once you learn to teach it. Big battery is useful when using as universal remote. WiFi signal is stronger than old Moto G - it's a better dongle, I get 16MBps on 3G. I had to flash it with Android 6 manually, it appears to be stock plus a few apps for now. Long may it last.

Comment: Having had the phone in practice for a while now, I cannot recommend it for one reason in particular - there appears to be insufficient thermal protection in the electronics of mine - heavy loading of those 8 cores caused the battery to swell. In the UK I also had problems with retailers honoring the statutory 1 year warranty when the fingerprint sensor started malfunctioning now and then. So I then compromised on the IR and got a Lenovo P2, which has longer battery life with a slightly smaller battery.